# How to plot function embedded in module in Mathematica

Tags: module, visualization, wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot a 2D graph for this function.
[Efficiency of a SS topology resonant circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtO4g.png)
I am new to Mathematica. This is what I have tried, I would appreciate it if someone could help me troubleshoot it and post a working version.

```
Eff [d_,f_]:=Module[{C1,C2,L1,L2,R1,R2,Rs,Ro,a,b,w,mu,RL,M,eff,fr,Vi,N1,N2},
w = 2 Pi f;
C1 = 1/(L1*w^2);
C2= 1/(L2*w^2);
L1 = L2 = 14 10^-6;fr=270 10^3;
Ro=R1=R2=Rs=0.2;
a = b = 0.5; mu = 4 Pi*10^-7; Vi = 100;N1=N2=100;
M[d]=  N1 N2 Block[{k = Sqrt[(4 a b)/((a + b)^2 + d^2)]}, mu Sqrt[a b]  2/k ((1 - k^2/2) EllipticK[k^2] - EllipticE[k^2])];
eff =(C2^2*M[d]^2*Ro*w^4)/(R1 + Rs + C2*(-2*L2 + C2*(R2 + RL)^2)*(R1 + Rs)*w^2 + C22*(M [d]2*(R2 + RL) + L2^2*(R1 + Rs))*w^4)
]
Plot[Eff [0.1,f] ,{f,100 10^3,100 10^6}]
```

The values are test values. Please I will appreciate any help to make this work.

Comment: Third line from the bottom of your code you have `C22` Should that be `C2` or `C2*2`? Third line from the bottom of your code you have `RL` twice but that has never been initialized.  What value should `RL` have? If I change `C22` to `C2` and I insert a line `RL=1;` at the beginning of your `Module` and run it then I get a plot. Is that plot correct?

Comment: and a `Return[ eff ]` is probably helping.

Comment: ...also, you should set the value of `L1` etc before using it in evaluating `C1` etc. Actually, you can initialize this in the Module local variable definition section. (Note, some spaces or even new lines would make your code more readable)

Comment: Eventually, you are looking for `Plot3D`. 3D graphs are nice at the screen when one can rotate them. In all other cases a `ContourPlot` is probably better.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bill. You are very correct. I tried it and fixed the error. Grateful

Comment: @mikuszefski.. The suggestions are very well appreciated and noted... I agree. 
Do you mind sharing the Plot3D solution to this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is a version showing that *Mathematica* code does not need to look awful. :)

```
Eff[d_, f_] := Module[
  {
   L1 = 14 10^(-6),
   L2 = 14 10^(-6),
   R1 = 0.2,
   R2 = 0.2,
   Rs = 0.2,
   Ro = 0.2,
   a = 0.5,
   b = 0.5,
   w = 2 Pi f,
   mu = 4 Pi 10^(-7),
   RL = 1,
   N1 = 100,
   N2 = 100,
   C1, C2, M, k
  },
  C1 = 1 / (L1*w^2);
  C2 = 1 / (L2*w^2);
  k = Sqrt[
    (4 a b)/
     ((a + b)^2 + d^2)
    ];
  M = N1 N2 mu Sqrt[a b] 2 / k 
    ((1 - k^2 / 2) EllipticK[k^2] - EllipticE[k^2]);
  Return[
   (C2^2 M^2 Ro w^4) /
    (
     R1 + Rs
      + C2 (-2 L2 + C2 (R2 + RL)^2) (R1 + Rs) w^2
      + C2^2 (M^2 (R2 + RL) + L2^2 (R1 + Rs)) w^4 
     )
   ]
  ]
```

and

```
LogLinearPlot[
 Evaluate[
  Table[
   Eff[d, f], {d, 0.1, 1.1, 0.1}
   ]
  ], {f, 10^3, 10^8},
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Table[d, {d, 0.1, 1.1, 0.1}]
 ]
```

or

```
Plot3D[
 Eff[d, f], {d, 0.1, 1.1}, {f, 10^3, 10^8},
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Log", Identity},
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

Comment: You are an amazing teacher... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`fr` and `Vi` are not used.

```
Clear[L1, L2, Ro, R1, R2, Rs, a, b, mu, N1, N2, d]

M[d_] := Module[{k = Sqrt[(4 a b)/((a + b)^2 + d^2)]}, 
  N1 N2 mu Sqrt[a b] 2/k ((1 - k^2/2) EllipticK[k^2] - EllipticE[k^2])]

w[f_] := 2 Pi f
C1[f_] := 1/(L1*w[f]^2)
C2[f_] := 1/(L2*w[f]^2)

eff[d_, f_, RL_] := (C2[f]^2*M[d]^2*Ro*w[f]^4)/
  (R1 + Rs + C2[f]*(-2*L2 + C2[f]*(R2 + RL)^2)*(R1 + Rs)*w[f]^2 +
    C2[f]^2*(M[d]^2*(R2 + RL) + L2^2*(R1 + Rs))*w[f]^4)

L1 = L2 = 14 10^-6;
Ro = R1 = R2 = Rs = 0.2;
a = b = 0.5;
mu = 4 Pi*10^-7;
N1 = N2 = 100;
d = 0.1;

Legended[Show[Sequence @@
   Table[Plot[eff[d, f, RL], {f, 100 10^3, 100 10^6}, 
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, Round[5 RL + 1]],
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"  f", "eff"})],
    {RL, 0, 1, 0.2}], PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 LineLegend[ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range[6],
  Table["RL=" <> ToString[RL], {RL, 0, 1, 0.2}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you... this is also Interesting
Although I already solved it with @Bill's comment, but this approach introduces me to more functions